# API Authentication from Google Chrome in Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, urllib

I apologize in advance as I'm pretty new to this stuff. I've seen similar questions, but just can't figure out my particular situation.

I'm trying to use an API through Python, but can't figure out how to authenticate and there is no documentation. I use a service that has a website. The website seems to be powered by an API. Therefore, when I trace all of my network traffic through ctrl-shift-I, I can see all the API calls I need to use as I click through the website. So, even though the API isn't documented, I know all of the end points I need.

Once I login to my account via the website, the API is authenticated. I can then make requests in the browser to the API. However, I can't seem to figure out how to authenticate via Python in the requests library. I'm open to any manner of authenticating, and have even tried using cookies from my browser per other suggestions on Stack Overflow, but I'm very unfamiliar with that method.

Am I completely missing something here? Most of these methods of authenticating I've found as solutions in Stack Overflow that seem to work for others.

```
s = requests.Session()
payload = {'usernameOrEmail': 'XXXXXXX', 'password':'XXXXXXX'}
s.post('https://XXXXXXX', json=payload, headers={'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.81 Safari/537.36'})

s = requests.Session()
payload = {'usernameOrEmail': 'XXXXXXX', 'password':'XXXXXXX'}
s.post('https://XXXXXXX', json=payload)


url = 'https://XXXXXXX'
    values = {'usernameOrEmail': 'XXXXXXX',
              'password': 'XXXXXXX'}

r = requests.post(url, data=values, verify=False)
```

I've tried using the URL of the login page, the member overview page that you are forwarded to after logging in, the API URL's/endpoints, etc. I'm 98% sure I have the name value pairs correct for username and password.

I've even tried a simple get request and appending the usernameOrEmail and password fields on the URL.

I've gotten 401's, 404's, and a 405 most recently depending on the URL method combination.

Apologies in advance as I'm sure this is something extremely basic. Am I on the right track with submitting Username and Password or do I need to go the route of using browser cookies?

I'm using Spyder through Anaconda.

Thanks

Updated for Code Producing a 404:

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()

payload = {'username_or_email': 'XXXXXXX', 'password':'XXXXXXX'}

test=s.post('https://members.onepeloton.com/login', json=payload)

print(test)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing HTTP related you can't do in Python that you can do in your browser, except for running Javascript.

You're probably missing a request or some parameter. Maybe there has been a cookie set from before you started you browser session.

Try recording and emulating all the requests from an incognito tab, that way you're sure you start with the same state as your Python session.

Maybe we can help you more if you can tell us which website you're trying to authenticate to.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I know I'm pretty new to this in general, especially with authentications.Here is the login page:

https://members.onepeloton.com/login

Comment: So, just had a look at the login endpoint. And it seems that you mispelled a parameter. Use `username_or_email` instead of usernameOrEmail. Also your header that starts with: Mozilla, should be a dict that has a "User-Agent" key.

Comment: Thanks. I saw in the source that it was usernameOrEmail,  but maybe I was looking in the wrong place. I included that header, because I saw some comments were made in other posts saying that sometimes websites will block automated requests.

So without the header would something this simple work:

s = requests.Session()
payload = {'username_or_email': 'XXXXXXX', 'password':'XXXXXXX'}
test=s.post('https://members.onepeloton.com/login', json=payload)
print(test)

Comment: I'm now getting an error:


I'm now getting:

SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='members.onepeloton.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /login (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))

Comment: I tried changing the code to add verify=False as I saw in another Stack Overflow post but get the same error

Comment: Their certificate appears to be valid: https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=members.onepeloton.com && https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=members.onepeloton.com&latest

Might you be working on a virtual machine that has misconfigured date-time?

Comment: Thanks again. I got it working but realized it's due to being behind a company network and requiring a certificate. I tried the following but now get an error:  

import requests

s = requests.Session()
payload = {'username_or_email': 'XXXXXXX', 'password':'XXXXXXX'}
test=s.post('https://members.onepeloton.com/login', json=payload, cert='C:/Users/XXXXXXX/ca-bundle.crt', verify=True)
print(test)  

Error: [('PEM routines', 'get_name', 'no start line'), ('SSL routines', 'SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file', 'PEM lib')]  

I'm going to run the code again once off network to see if it resolves

Comment: ok, I'm not behind anything blocking my authentication and now I'm getting a 404 error. Obviously the page exist, so I'm not sure why it wouldnt work now. I'm adding to my original question the code that gives a 404

Comment: Ok I figured it out. It was being redirected to the API for authentication, which is a different URL. I think I have this working now thank you!